# How to change CIFilter value of video using UISlider?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, uislider, cifilter

I am trying to add CIFilters to video. But I change the values using UISliders because of AVPlayer take time to play filter added video. I search of this issue, UISlider values continuously changing and it takes float values as well. Because of every time filter add to video and play. I want to know how to change values of CIFilter and without delay of AVPlayer when slider value change continuously.

```
float value = sender.value;
CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorControls"];
AVVideoComposition *composition = [AVVideoComposition videoCompositionWithAsset:tempAVAsset applyingCIFiltersWithHandler:
                                   ^(AVAsynchronousCIImageFilteringRequest *request){
                                       NSError *err = nil;
                                       CIImage *filtered = [request.sourceImage imageByClampingToExtent];
                                       [filter setDefaults];
                                       [filter setValue:filtered forKey:kCIInputImageKey];

                                       [filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.00] forKey:@"inputSaturation"];
                                       [filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.00] forKey:@"inputBrightness"];
                                       [filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:value] forKey:@"inputContrast"];

                                       CIImage *output = [filter.outputImage imageByCroppingToRect:request.sourceImage.extent];
                                       if (filtered)
                                           [request finishWithImage:output context:nil];
                                       else
                                           [request finishWithError:err];

                                   }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just change the filter parameter outside of your composition block when the slider value changes and don't re-set it inside the block. So just do

```
[adjustFilter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:sender.value] forKey:@"inputContrast"];
```

inside your `valueChanged` callback instead of inside the composition block. This way the filter always gets the most current value and will use it for the next video frame.

**Edit:**

Here are some parts of a possible implementation inside a view controller:

```
@interface DemoViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) CIFilter *filter;
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVPlayer *player;
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAsset *tempAVAsset;

@end

@implementation DemoViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // setup filter
    self.filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorControls"];
    [self.filter setDefaults];
    [self.filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.00] forKey:@"inputSaturation"];
    [self.filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.00] forKey:@"inputBrightness"];

    AVVideoComposition *composition = [AVVideoComposition videoCompositionWithAsset:self.tempAVAsset applyingCIFiltersWithHandler:
        ^(AVAsynchronousCIImageFilteringRequest *request){
            NSError *err = nil;
            CIImage *filtered = [request.sourceImage imageByClampingToExtent];

            [self.filter setValue:filtered forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
            CIImage *output = [self.filter.outputImage imageByCroppingToRect:request.sourceImage.extent];
            if (filtered)
               [request finishWithImage:output context:nil];
            else
               [request finishWithError:err];
        }
    ];

    // setup player with composition
    // ...
}


- (IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider*)sender
{
    // get the new slider value and assign it to the filter
    [self.filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:sender.value] forKey:@"inputContrast"];
}

@end
```

Comment: I have error do like that. [<CIExposureAdjust 0x280459380> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]

Comment: `CIExposureAdjust` doesn’t have an `inputContrast`. In your code above you were using a `CIColorControls` filter.

Comment: I try different cifilters. Now no errors but problem is I added the line of code outside the completion block no changes in avplayer.

Comment: Where does `adjustFilter` come from? It needs to be the same instance in the composition block and when applying the slider value.

Comment: What's the scope of this whole code? Are you creating a new composition every time the slider value changes?

Comment: I am trying to add CIFilter to video file. In here I am change value of CIFilter using UISlider. But the problem is avplayer take time to play when filter value changed. Yes, I am creating new composition every time. Because of, I want new composition for avplayer.

Comment: But you don't need to create a new composition just because a value of the filter changed. The block in your composition is called every time the player tries to display a new frame. So when the parameter of the filter changes, the next frame will be reflecting that change even without creating a new composition.

Comment: Can you send an example code? I google it about this issue. Many of they suggest use GLKView or MTKView for this. They said these view give better performance for video processing. Please guide me.

Comment: I want to show live change in filter because of every time i was create new composition.

Comment: Ya, but i want all three values(Saturation, brightness and Contrast). I want show video with these value changes. Help me.

Comment: Then you need to add three sliders, each with their own `IBAction` and in each action you change a different parameter of the filter.

Comment: Ya, You are correct, but every time it is create new composition. Because of, delay in avplayer to update current change.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. The way I set it up it should only create one composition in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: I am applying CIFilters to video, Avplayer little delay to preview the video. In this case i am not change filter value. I think previous problem also like this. My understanding is value change or not, AVplayer take time to preview new video change. Guide me.

Comment: Now it is working better than before. Thanks a lot.